# Python: creating variable name from header row in csv read

Tags: python

I have looked for the answered questions but my case is different.

I am reading a large csv file with a header row and has 50 names in the header corresponding to 50 data columns in csv file. I want to create 50 arrays and each array will store data as I proceed to read and parse the file line by line. I want to store the 50 arrays in variable names same as the column name read the header line.

Comment: thats not really how you do it (you can... but you should use a dict...)

Comment: I am very new to python so can u give me an example how i can create an empty array for value when the key are variables. I am struggling with creating such dictionary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = csv.reader(open("my_text.csv"))
columns = zip(*data)
dataMap = {d[0]:d[1:] for d in columns}
print dataMap["Timestamp"] # or whatever
```

is a much preferred method ... if you really want variable names try

```
globals().update({d[0]:d[1:] for d in columns})
print Timestamp # or whatever
```

but I strongly advise against this

really what it sounds like you want is `pandas.DataFrame.from_csv` though

```
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv("data.txt")

print df["Timestamp"] # or whatever your header names might be
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer to the question, but definitely the solution to the problem.

Comment: Both of the above solution will load the entire data into the RAM and for a large dataset that will cause memory error ?

Comment: python32 limits you to 2 GB of ram ... 64 limits you to the ammount of ram you have available ... yes you can crash it ... if you are dealing with datasets that large then you will need to think of the problem differently (your "explained" solution in the OP also would load the entire dataset into memory) ... if thats the case you may want to look at a database or some other structure that allows you to work with very large data sets

Comment: ...  if you explain "why" you are trying to do this then perhaps I can help you come up with a less memory intensive solution... but remember everything comes with tradeoffs (often you will trade RAM for speed)